# MySQL - Now() only insert date value into DateTime column

Tags: mysql

I had a table with a `datetime` type column. When I use `Now()` to insert the value. It's only have date value without time value inserted.

It's does show date & time when run select `Now()` in query screen `2019-09-06 14:48:54`

But when perform

```
insert into table1 values (col1, col2, col3, Now());
```

It's inserted `2019-09-06 00:00:00`
Supposedly have time as well `2019-09-06 14:22:56`

Comment: did you try changing the `datatype` to `timestamp`?

Comment: If your target column is of the appropriate type this should not be a problem.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Is it possible that you ran the insert query at exactly 12AM?

Comment: share us the `create table` statement. Have you tried to insert datetime explicitly rather than now()?

Comment: To insert only date value, use curdate() in MySQL. With that, if you want to get the entire datetime, then you can use now() method. Maybe you can check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-insert-current-date-time

Comment: @SalmanA The question says that he ran it at 14:48:54.

Comment: Please share more details such that one can reproduce that problem

Comment: Show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`.

Comment: Include the datatypes of the columns, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the column type to timestamp and it's solved the problem. Previously I created the column type using DateTime only. Not using DateTime().

Comment: This should have been an edit to the question. Just to be clear you defined the column as datetime() (exactly as written)?

Answer (score 0):

Ive just tested it in my own database;

And It works perfectly.

```
 create table myTable(myDates datetime(6));

 insert into table (myDates) values (NOW());
```

Comment: I had resolved the problem by changing the column type to timestamp.

Comment: sometimes its a bug with in the version of mysql.